# How to filter an Array with another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an Array of Objects:

```
const array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }]
```

I have a second array containing the ID's that I want to filter out of the first Array:

```
const ids = [1, 2]
```

How do I create a new Array of Objects without the ID's found in `ids`.

Comment: Do you want a new array, or to mutate the existing one?

Comment: Whenever there's a question asking how to perform deletions on an array, you end up with a bunch of answers showing how to make a new array and overwrite the original. *Those are not equivalent operations.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a fairly simple `filter` operation

```js
const array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];

const ids = [1, 2];

var result = array.filter( x => !ids.includes(x.id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to mutate the original array you can do like this:

```js
const array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];

const ids = [1, 2];

ids.forEach(idToDelete => {
    const index = array.findIndex(({ id }) => id === idToDelete);
    array.splice(index, 1);
});

console.log(array);
```

If you need a new array you can do like this:

```js
const array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];

const ids = [1, 2];

const result = array.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

You could also reassign a new array to the `array` variable:

```js
let array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];

const ids = [1, 2];

array = array.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why `.find()` the object, and then go back to get its index? That's twice as much work as needed. Use `.findIndexx()` or use a traditional loop,

Comment: At least use `findIndex` if you're going to do it this way to save having to enumerate twice for every element in `ids`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.filter` :

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1, bar: "test" },
  {id: 2, bar: "test2" },
  {id: 3, bar: "test3" }
];

let ids = [1,2];

let filteredArray = array.filter(row=>!ids.includes(row.id));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: You're not deleting anything from the first array. Maybe the OP is fine with creating a new array, but the question does ask for mutation of the original.

Comment: @slappy just use ```array``` variable instead of ```filteredArray``` if you need dispose the main array from memory.

Comment: What if the OP has multiple references to the original array? You shouldn't assume that overwriting an array will be adequate when they ask for mutations.

Comment: Why i shoud not? It seems cost of traversing array using findIndex and splice is same as filter if it is not more.

Comment: It's not about performance; it's that they're not equivalent operations. If the OP has multiple references to `array`, and you overwrite one of them with the changes, the other references will not see the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this oneliner from lodash.

```
const _ = require("lodash");
let filteredArray = _.remove(array, el=>[1,2].includes(el.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `indexOf`.

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, bar: 'test' }, { id: 2, bar: 'test2' }, { id: 3, bar: 'test3' }];
const ids = [1, 2];

const result = arr.filter(element => ids.indexOf(element.id) === -1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can filter an array in JavaScript using Array filter()

```
const myArray = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }]
const ids = [1,2]

const resultArray = myArray.filter(item => !ids.includes(item.id));
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Those double quotes (`„`, `”`) are not `"` and throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

In term of performance the best solution will be the next one:

```
let array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];
const ids = [1,2];
const idSet = new Set();
for (const id of ids) {
 idSet.add(id);
}

array = array.filter(x => !set.has(x.id));
//const newArray if you need the initial array unmodified
```

In this case we perform two consequencial iteration instead of a nested one, so the time complexity will be O(n) instead of O(n^2);

##Edit

If you instead need the initial array to be mutated and not overwritten you can use this approach:

```js
    const ids = [1,2];
    const array = [{id: 1, bar: "test" }, {id: 2, bar: "test2" }, {id: 3, bar: "test3" }];

    for (const id of ids) {
    const index = array.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    array.splice(index, 1);

}
```

In the second case the time complexity will be O(n*m), where n is array length and m is ids length.

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose something wildly different.

In my case, I wanted to filter one list of unique IDs against another.

I was curious if regex could do it faster.

- Such a method really only works with one-dimensional arrays of simple objects.

  - It's probably best if items a single regex 'word' (string of 0-9a-z_).
  - A list of ids works perfect.
- array.filter works best on small datasets (1,000), usually slightly faster
- regex worked 66% faster on large datasets (10,000)
- regex speed advantage widens. 90% faster on 100,000.
- On comparing two arrays of 1m items, filter didn't do anything for me after more than 90 seconds. Regex returned a result in six seconds.
- In this case, the input is number[], and the output is string[], which works for my purposes, but you can use `map` to convert back to numbers if you need, .

```js
var listlength = 10000;

function createArray() {
  let arr = new Set();

  for (let i = 0; i < listlength; i++) {
    arr.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * listlength));
  }

  return arr;
}

function filter() {
  let arr1 = Array.from(createArray());
  let arr2 = Array.from(createArray());


  let start = +new Date();
  let arr3 = arr1.filter((n) => !arr2.includes(n));

  console.log('filter', (+new Date() - start) + 'ms', arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length);
}

function regex() {
  let arr1 = Array.from(createArray());
  let arr2 = Array.from(createArray());

  let start = +new Date();
  let str1 = arr1.join(',') + ',';
  str1 = str1.replace(new RegExp('\\b(' + arr2.join('|') + '),', 'g'), '');

  let result = str1.split(',') // .map(e=>Number(e)); (to convert back to number[])
  result.pop();
  console.log('regex', (+new Date() - start) + 'ms', arr1.length, arr2.length, result.length);
}

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log(`try ${x}`);
  filter();
  regex();
}
```

On my NodeJS app, sets of 100,000, regex more than 90% faster.

[image]